# Rails acts_as_audited - why does it index by ID first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Using Rails 2.3.5.

In acts_as_audited, the schema definition defines an index:

> add_index :audits, [:auditable_id,
>   :auditable_type], :name =>
>   'auditable_index'

It seems to me that the index should be:

> add_index :audits, [:auditable_type,
>   :auditable_id], :name =>
>   'auditable_index'

In general, in a polymorphic association, we might sometimes want to search by the type only, but hardly ever search by the ID without the type?

Or is this a lazy way to allow a search by auditable_id when you are only using the plugin to audit one table?

Or is there another reason to do the indexing this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer just occurred to me.

Some databases don't support multi-field indexing,and those databases will index only the first field.  If you go with my alternate indexing, then you'd get data clustered by class name, on which the database will have to do a sequential scan to find a particular ID.  That's bound to be slower than searching for IDs and then checking the class name.

Another reason, I've found, is that SQL optimizers tend to not figure out to use an index when the first field in the index is not specific enough, apparently.